# Declare only one variable(template) using if condition in C++

Tags: c++, templates

I want to create a single object of template class "stack" using if condition as shown below and use it outside the if condition.

```
template <class TYPE>

class stack{
..
..
};
main()
{
int opt;
cin>>opt;
```

Here is the if condition

```
if(opt == 1)
    stack<int> s;
else
    stack<float> s;

s.push(1);
}
```

The problem I am facing is the object "s" is being created in block scope and I am not able to access that object outside if condition.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Lookup SFINAE. This can't be done with `if()`.

Comment: I wish to declare single variable "s" using if condition and use it outside if condition.

Comment: @CHAITANYA Well, you can't do that because you want the variable's type to depend on a runtime conditon. That cannot be done in C++ (but look at `boost::variant` for a different approach.)

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple. Just put the common code in a function template.

```
template< class Number >
void foo()
{
    stack<Number> s;
    s.push( 1 );
}

auto main() -> int
{
    int opt;
    cin>>opt;
    opt == 1? foo<int>() : foo<double>();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The type of `s` has to be known before runtime, but you could use an interface like this:

```
class stackI{};

template <class TYPE>
class stack : public stackI {
    std::vector<TYPE> values;
    /*...*/
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    stackI* s;
    if (1==0){
        s = new stack<int>;
    } else {
        s = new stack<double>;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am getting this error.. stack_tmp1.cpp:(.text._ZN6stackIC2Ev[_ZN6stackIC5Ev]+0x8): undefined reference to `vtable for stackI'

Comment: @CHAITANYA well, I have to admit, that the interface isnt very useful, because without casting, you cannot call any method on `s`

Comment: I was making the functions(push,pop) in base class as virtual. The problem was solved when I made it pure virtual.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I've found the answer.
Make funtions as "pure virtual" in base class.
Define the pure virtual functions in derived class.
Declare Base type pointer *s in main(),
then 
`s = new stackDerived<int>` or `s = new stackDerived<char>` within if condition.

```
class stackBase{
    public:

    virtual void push()    = 0;  //pure virtual function
    virtual void pop()     = 0;  //pure virtual function   
    virtual void display() = 0;  //pure virtual function   
};

template <typename T>
class stackDerived : public stackBase{

    T data[100];
    int top;
public:
    void push()
    {
    T ele;
    cin>>ele;
    }
//definitions of pop and display are also included in this class
};

int main()
{
stackBase *s;
if(condition)
    s = new stackDerived<int>;
else
    s = new stackDerived<char>;

within switch case
s->push(integer or character as required);
}
```